# Bold/normal in one word with markdown

Tags: support, markdown

How to I write some parts in a word in bold with the markdown of Stack Overflow?

I like to highlight a specific part of a "word" for example the last 2 numbers:

> 1234**56**

why do I have to write a space before the `**` to get it working:

> 1234 **56**

Is there a possibility to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using the subset of HTML elements allowed by Markdown: `1234<strong>56</strong>` or `1234<b>56</b>`.

Result:

> 1234**56**

Comment: cross-site dupe at MSE suggests zero width space for that: [How do I make part of a word bold using Markdown?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140709/165773) (it also warns that ZWSP won't work in comments)